# Constraint violation for Linear Integer Programming in Python Gurobi

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi, integer-programming

I am trying to implement LIP in Gurobi but somehow the constraints related to single edge into the node and single edge out of the node is being violated. The following are the equations (**I am not copying the equations exactly interms of the summations limits so its (i,j) 0 - N for now, however the constraint should not be violated regardless** )

[image]

So the bottom equation simply states that there should be one edge coming in and leaving the vertex or node. However in the following code I added this constraint but somehow it is getting violated in the result.

I have quite exhausted my head trying to figure out what might be the issue

```
import gurobipy as grb
import math
n = 4

set_I = range(0, n)
set_J = range(0, n)


Distance = 50000000


def distance(points, i, j):
  dx = points[i][0] - points[j][0]
  dy = points[i][1] - points[j][1]
  return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

random.seed(1)
points = []
for i in range(n):
  points.append((random.randint(0,100),random.randint(0,100)))

opt_model = grb.Model(name="MILP Model")


x_vars = {}
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(n):
     x_vars[i,j] = opt_model.addVar(vtype=grb.GRB.BINARY,
                          name='e'+str(i)+'_'+str(j))
# <= Constraint (Distance)

for i in range(n):
  opt_model.addConstr(grb.quicksum(x_vars[i,j]*distance(points, i, j) for j in range(n)) <= Distance)
  x_vars[i,i].ub = 0

# <= Constraint (coming in to node and going out should be 1 each)
for i in range(n):
  opt_model.addConstr(grb.quicksum(x_vars[i,j] for j in range(n)) <= 1)
opt_model.update()

# <= objective is to maximize

objective = grb.quicksum(x_vars[i,j]
                         for i in set_I
                         for j in set_J)
opt_model.ModelSense = grb.GRB.MAXIMIZE
opt_model.setObjective(objective)
opt_model.update()

opt_model.optimize()
solution = opt_model.getAttr('x', x_vars )

print solution

import pandas as pd
opt_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x_vars, orient="index",
                                columns = ["variable_object"])
opt_df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(opt_df.index,
                               names=["column_i", "column_j"])
opt_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
# Gurobi
opt_df["solution_value"] = opt_df["variable_object"].apply(lambda item: item.X)

print opt_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you did not add the constraint of equal

according to your code, it should be something like

```py
for k in range(1, n-1):
  opt_model.addConstr(grb.quicksum(x_vars[i,k] for i in range(n-1)) 
                      == grb.quicksum(x_vars[k,j] for j in range(1, n)))
```

and actually, your objective function should be like the following code according to your equation

```py
objective = grb.quicksum(x_vars[i,j]
                         for i in range(1, n-1)
                         for j in range(1, n)
```

Comment: It appears that this solves the problem of single edge in and out, but I still didnt understand why equality constraint should solve this when I was explicitly telling that for all permutations of Sum x(i,j) there should be 1 edge going out. Why was I seeing 2 or even 3 edges going out of a node? What difference does the equality constraint make?

Comment: moreover although the constraint that x(i,j) = x(j,i) has been added, it still gives back and forth edges in the solution such as x(0,4) and x(4,0). Any workaround for that?

Comment: please do care to chick this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58509173/solution-not-feasible-in-linear-programming-in-python-gurobi) i posted